# Integrate solr with spring application

Tags: hibernate, spring, struts2, solr

How can I integrate solr in my spring and struts application. 
Is it an overkill for small applications as I am just developing a college project

Answer (score 1):

Sumit what exactly are your requirements? As you can always do a small POC and i have answered in other post Solr is an standalone enterprise search server so it does not matter to it if you are using Spring,Struts,Wicket or any other framework. All it needs the data sources from where it needs to collect data for indexing be it your database,file system or any other data over web.
It has some out of the box data-handlers which knows how to handle and read/parse data from the source you have configured,when you ask Solr to give data against the search it will hand over the data to you as per your search criteria and now its in your hands how you use the data and use it.

i hope this will help you in understanding the concept.

Comment: I want to use it for basic file system and database search. Can it only run as standalone server, can we not deploy it with our web application in tomcat and restrict access to it with spring security. What changes need to be made to our web.xml to integrate it. Also I want to know the basic steps of setting it up and configuring it to use my database

Comment: @Sumit:All things you will get to know on Solr web page how to configure it and yes you can yes you can use the war of Solr in your tomcat and access it as a web service.

Comment: The thing i want to know which i am not getting any info about is that can i integrate solr in my web application which means can i deploy it inside my application or i have to deploy it seperately

Comment: @Sumit: I told you that Solr is in war is also available all you need to do is to extract it in the web apps folder where your application is running and communicate it using HTTP system or web-service and yes if you want to integrate it inside your application as embedded type i believe you need to do a lot of work and understanding of the system

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EmbeddedSolr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr) to fully integrate Solr into your webapp.  You won't need to deploy any extra WARs, just the one for your webapp.

This will fire up Solr within your app and let you access it directly.  The nice thing about this is that the interface is exactly the same as accessing it via HTTP to a standalone server, meaning if you change your mind later on it will only be a single line change

Comment: Hi @MrWiggles, just fyi they've really backed away from embedding Solr.  For one thing, if memory issues are encountered, it's harder to isolate.